# Date Range to save database using Listview

Tags: vb.net

Any one help me,
I have to DateTimePicker i need loop condition fill listview two DateTimePicker. and save them database using Selected Checkbox (Listview checkbox) and one textbox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTsQW.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This Logic...

```
 For count = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
     If DataGridView1.Rows(count).Cells(0).Value = True Then
         'SQL INSERT COMMAND HERE
     End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a ListView, you need to iterate the CheckedItems collection:

```
 For Each lvi As ListViewItem in myLv.CheckedItems
     ' SQL operation using lvi.SubItems for the values
 Next
```

This will work on all the items checked (as per the question) not just the one singled out in the image.  you could also iterate `CheckedIndices` as an index into `Items()`.